# How to launch an EXE from Web page with asp.net4

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, wsh, jscript

i use this code:

```
<script>
function LaunchApp() {
    if (!document.all) {
        alert("Available only with Internet Explorer.");
        return;
    }
    var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    ws.Exec("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
}
```

```
<a href="javascript:LaunchApp()">Launch the executable</a>
```

but this not work. (Link is disabled)

Comment: You need very specific permissions in IE to have this work properly ..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: whats specific permissions in IE? please help me

Comment: @nas105 I've re-tagged your question. This isn't about ASP.NET, .NET or C#. It's about JScript and IE.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are not pointing to the same JavaScript function. Try this:

   `<button onclick="LaunchApp()">Run Exe File</button>`
2. Your internet settings must be set to the **lowest security level** possible to allow you to run this kind of code.

Comment: Excuse me. I mistakenly wrote. Edited... please help me for internet settings.